# Drawing text on top of 3D shapes in Processing has depth issues

Tags: opengl, 3d, processing

Playing around with Processing, I came to a situation where I want to draw text on top of 3D objects being transformed:

```java
pushMatrix();
noFill();
stroke(c, 128);
translate(width/2, height/2);
// misc. 3D drawing code goes here. Finally draw text:
fill(255);
textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
text("...ןעוט", width/2, height/2);
```

The resulting image has a depth problem. Anything behind the text appears to be black for no good reason. See image below:

[image: The depth problem]

I don't want this to happen. I want the text to be see-through where it needs to be. How would I solve this?

Comment: In the future, you should try to provide a [mcve] that we can run. Even a basic example with a simple cube and some text would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I can't explain exactly why and how but what I did was add:

```
textMode(SHAPE);
```

Which solved the issue. Somehow.

Comment: the default text mode is TEXTURE which essentially is a rectangle with the text pixels on top. [textMode(SHAPE)](https://processing.org/reference/textMode_.html) will draw the geometry(vertices/faces) for each letter/glyth. Well done on figuring it out and sharing (+1)